# GMAT starts simulating in 1990, how do I change that?

Tags: orbital-elements

I'm running a simulation of a few satellites using their TLE epochs and other orbital parameters. GMAT gives the correct dates when writing the report output, but the contact locator and spacecraft ephemeris files have the epochs starting on 1990-06-15T09:00:47.057 UTC. Under the Resources tab, I've given the start epoch as the correct epoch date from the TLE, but to no avail. What am I missing?

Comment: Have you tried HORIZONS for orbital parameters prior to 1990? https://ssd.jpl.nasa.gov/horizons.cgi